# Cannot Scale Integral Symbol using scaleobj

Tags: scale

Hi I'm try to reduce the size of my integral sign so it fits within the same line as the rest of my equation. I tried using scaleobj to reduce the size, but I cannot figure out why I'm getting an "undefined control sequence" error using the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle V(t) = \cos{(\omega_{c}t}+k \scaleobj{.2}{\int}f(t)dt)  
\label{fmmod}
\end{equation}
```

How am I using \scaleobj incorrectly?

Comment: as always on the site please provide a full (but minimal) example, not sniplets. Where does `\scaleobj` come from? Additionally `\displaystyle` does nothing here as you are already in display style

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by adding a necessary package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, after reading daleif's comment I realised that \scaleobj is not a native latex function. It comes from the scalerel package. After adding the package it works as expected.